# Alert Dialog positive button issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

I am developing an app that asks the user to type task's name, description....,but when the user intends to leave the edit page without saving the task I need to pop up a dialog to confirm leaving, so if he clicked abandon changes he must return to the home page of the app otherwise he will stay at the same page.

I have problem with this, when the user clicks abandon changes the dialog dismisses and he stays at the edit page.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package muhabalafandi.example.tasktimer

import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.content_main.*


private const val TAG = "MainActivity"
private const val DIALOG_ID_CANCEL_EDIT = 1

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), AddEditFragment.OnSaveClicked,
    MainActivityFragment.OnTaskEdit,
    AppDialog.DialogEvents {


    // Whether or the activity is in 2-pane mode
    // i.e. running in landscape, or on a tablet.
    private var mTwoPane = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: starts")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        mTwoPane = resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: twoPane is $mTwoPane")

        val fragment = findFragmentById(R.id.task_details_container)
        if (fragment != null) {
            // There was an existing fragment to edit a task, make sure the panes are set correctly
            showEditPane()
        } else {
            task_details_container.visibility = if (mTwoPane) View.INVISIBLE else View.GONE
            mainFragment.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: finished")
    }

    private fun showEditPane() {
        task_details_container.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        // hide the left hand pane, if in single pane view
        mainFragment.visibility = if (mTwoPane) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE

    }

    private fun removeEditPane(fragment: Fragment? = null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "removeEditPane called")
        if (fragment != null) {
//            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
//                .remove(fragment)
//                .commit()
            removeFragment(fragment)
        }

        // Set the visibility of the right hand pane
        task_details_container.visibility = if (mTwoPane) View.INVISIBLE else View.GONE
        // and show the left hand pane
        mainFragment.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)

    }

    override fun onSaveClicked() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveClicked: called")
        removeEditPane(findFragmentById(R.id.task_details_container))
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.menuMain_addTask -> taskEditRequest(null)
//            R.id.menuMain_settings -> true
            android.R.id.home -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "onOptionsItemSelected: home button pressed")
                val fragment = findFragmentById(R.id.task_details_container)
//                removeEditPane(fragment)
                if ((fragment is AddEditFragment) && fragment.isDirty()) {
                    showConfirmationDialog(
                        DIALOG_ID_CANCEL_EDIT,
                        getString(R.string.cancelEditDialogMessage),
                        R.string.cancelEditDialogPositiveCaption,
                        R.string.cancelEditDialogNegativeCaption
                    )
                    Log.d(TAG, "dialogId : $DIALOG_ID_CANCEL_EDIT")
                } else {
                    removeEditPane(fragment)
                }
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onTaskEdit(task: Task) {
        taskEditRequest(task)
    }

    private fun taskEditRequest(task: Task?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "taskEditRequest: starts")

        // Create a new fragment to edit the task
//        val newFragment = AddEditFragment.newInstance(task)
//        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
//            .replace(R.id.task_details_container, newFragment)
//            .commit()
        replaceFragment(AddEditFragment.newInstance(task), R.id.task_details_container)
        showEditPane()

        Log.d(TAG, "Exiting taskEditRequest")
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        val fragment = findFragmentById(R.id.task_details_container)
        if (fragment == null || mTwoPane) {
            super.onBackPressed()
        } else {
//            removeEditPane(fragment)
            if ((fragment is AddEditFragment) && fragment.isDirty()) {
                showConfirmationDialog(
                    DIALOG_ID_CANCEL_EDIT,
                    getString(R.string.cancelEditDialogMessage),
                    R.string.cancelEditDialogPositiveCaption,
                    R.string.cancelEditDialogNegativeCaption
                )
            } else {
                removeEditPane(fragment)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onPositiveDialogResult(dialogId: Int, args: Bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPositiveDialogResult: called with dialogId $dialogId")
        if (dialogId == DIALOG_ID_CANCEL_EDIT) {
            val fragment = findFragmentById(R.id.task_details_container)
            removeEditPane(fragment)
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart: called")
        super.onStart()
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState: called")
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume: called")
        super.onResume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause: called")
        super.onPause()
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState: called")
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop: called")
        super.onStop()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: called")
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

**AppDialog.kt**

```
package muhabalafandi.example.tasktimer

import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.app.Dialog
import android.content.Context
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment


private const val TAG = "AppDialog"

const val DIALOG_ID = "id"
const val DIALOG_MESSAGE = "message"
const val DIALOG_POSITIVE_RID = "positive_rid"
const val DIALOG_NEGATIVE_RID = "negative_rid"

class AppDialog : DialogFragment() {

    private var dialogEvents: DialogEvents? = null

    internal interface DialogEvents {
        fun onPositiveDialogResult(dialogId: Int, args: Bundle)
//        fun onNegativeDialogResult(dialogId: Int, args: Bundle)
//        fun onDialogCancelled(dialogId: Int)
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAttach called: context is $context")
        super.onAttach(context)

        // Activities/Fragments containing this fragment must implement its callbacks.
        dialogEvents = try {
            // Is there a parent fragment? If so, that will be what we call back
            parentFragment as? DialogEvents
        } catch (e: TypeCastException) {
            try {
                // No parent fragment, so call back the Activity instead
                context as DialogEvents
            } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
                // Activity doesn't implement the interface
                throw ClassCastException("Activity $context must implement AppDialog.DialogEvents interface")
            }
        } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
            // Parent fragment doesn't implement the interface
            throw ClassCastException("Fragment $parentFragment must implement AppDialog.DialogEvents interface")
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateDialog called")

        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())

        // fix "smart cast to Bundle is impossible, because 'arguments' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time"
        val arguments = arguments
        val dialogId: Int
        val messageString: String?
        var positiveStringId: Int
        var negativeStringId: Int

        if (arguments != null) {
            dialogId = arguments.getInt(DIALOG_ID)
            messageString = arguments.getString(DIALOG_MESSAGE)

            if (dialogId == 0 || messageString == null) {
                throw IllegalArgumentException("DIALOG_ID and/or DIALOG_MESSAGE not present in the bundle")
            }

            positiveStringId = arguments.getInt(DIALOG_POSITIVE_RID)
            if (positiveStringId == 0) {
                positiveStringId = R.string.ok
            }
            negativeStringId = arguments.getInt(DIALOG_NEGATIVE_RID)
            if (negativeStringId == 0) {
                negativeStringId = R.string.cancel
            }
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Must pass DIALOG_ID and DIALOG_MESSAGE in the bundle")
        }

        return builder.setMessage(messageString).setPositiveButton(positiveStringId) { _, _ ->
            // callback positive result function
            dialogEvents?.onPositiveDialogResult(dialogId, arguments)
        }.setNegativeButton(negativeStringId) { _, _ ->
            // callback negative result function, if you want to implement it.
            // dialogEvents?.onNegativeDialogResult(dialogId, arguments)
        }.create()
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDetach called")
        super.onDetach()

        // Reset the active callbacks interface, because we're no longer attached.
        dialogEvents = null
    }

    override fun onCancel(dialog: DialogInterface) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCancel called")
        val dialogId = requireArguments().getInt(DIALOG_ID)
//        dialogEvents?.onDialogCancelled(dialogId)
    }
}
```

Comment: use a callback function, close the drawer, and `pop` the fragment from the stack...

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not with popping up the fragment. It is that the dialog does not reach the onPositiveDialogResult function that is meant to close the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

```
buttonYes.setOnClickListener {
     findNavController().popBackStack()
     findNavController().popBackStack()
 {
```

Comment: a) Where does this go? b) Why two opening braces? Is there more to this code that you left out?